# Gremlin query to count vertices without a certain edge

Tags: graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have a Neptune database in AWS with the following graph:

[image: Graph]

So there's a user that organizes a party and has created two invitations. But the user has withdrawn one of these invitations.

I'm looking for a query to count the number of invitations that haven't been withdrawn (1 in the case above).

I've found a way to get the invitations (I'm using the [Gremlin package for Javascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gremlin)):

```
const result = await g
        .V("user#123")
        .inE().hasLabel("createdBy")
        .otherV()
        .toList();
```

But I can't seem to find anything to filter those invitations out that have been withdrawn. I don't think I can traverse to the edges that are not `withdrawnBy` because that would still return 2 (because we have a `createdBy` and a `withdrawnBy` edge).

Anyone have any pointers? I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837082/gremlin-how-do-you-find-vertices-without-a-particular-edge), which recommends:

```
gremlin> g.V.filter{!it.bothE('knows').hasNext()}
```

This is Groovy I assume, but I'm using Javascript (Typescript actually). I've tried the `.filter()` function, but this seems to throw an error:

```
.filter(function(this: any) {
    return !this.bothE("isRevokedBy");
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
g.V("user#123").as('u').
  in('createdBy').
  not(where(out('withdrawnBy').as('u')))
```

example: https://gremlify.com/crjfj88qrtfd8

But I think it will better to add a property on the `createdBy` edge that indicates that is been revoke instead of adding another edge between them.

like this:

```
g.V("user#123").
  inE('createdBy').not(has('withdrawn', true)).outV()
```

example: https://gremlify.com/csfdv6w7325mb

As you're using the JavaScript package, this is code that would work:

```
const gremlin = require("gremlin");
const __ = gremlin.process.statics;
const traversal = gremlin.process.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;
const dc = new DriverRemoteConnection("ws://localhost:8182/gremlin");
const g = traversal().withRemote(dc);

const result = await g
    .V("user#123")
    .in_("createdBy")
    .where(__.not(__.out("withdrawnBy")))
    .toList()
```